# Making eyelid for eye, any tips?

Tags: modeling

Still working on the model and getting to the eyes and eyelid. Following a video on making the eyelid and the guy doesn't give any tips if I run into issues not making the eyelid move a certain way when trying to apply shapekeys to it

it moves like this on my end but

[image]

supposed to move like this [image]

how do I fix that ?

Comment: Hi maxartz, welcome to BSE. First of all, if you are referring to a tutorial, please add a link to the tutorial to your question. Second: it would be very helpful if we know what you did, and what you want to achieve. I don't understand what you want because one picture is often not enough to make it clear how it should move. Since it seems that you are a beginner, providing a blend file is a good idea.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lozdbh8UUlw

This is the tutorial I'm using to make the eyelids. not sure how to provide the blend flie. I was trying to create the eyelids to be movable for later rigging when the model is fully complete

Answer (score 1):

You achieve different movement because of 2 reasons.

1. Your rotation pivot (3d cursor) is placed far beneath the eyelid, while in a tutorial they have it in the center of the plane of the semisphere (where the object's origin (single orange dot) is).
2. You are selecting the whole mesh, while in a tutorial they select only 4 front faces. That leads to moving your semisphere as a whole rather than deforming it.

To solve this:

1. While in `object mode` press `shift+S` and choose "Cursor to active". This will move 3d cursor to your object's origin.
2. In edit mode select 4 faces like in a tutorial, press O (to activate proportional editing), scroll the mouse wheel to get influence of proportional editing as needed, and finally, rotate around needed axis.

Hope this helps.

Comment: that actually worked !! thank you

Comment: Don't mention it. I modeled eyelids for the first time myself about 2 weeks ago.